# How can I create an ADD gate for two quantum states?

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, quantum-state, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit

I want to create an ADD gate like this: [image]

in qiskit using elementary gates.

Can it be done?

Comment: Hello ! Did you check [this example in the textbook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-states/atoms-computation.html#4.-Example:-Creating-an-Adder-Circuit-)? It could be good for a first start :)

Comment: @Lena I also said the same thing regarding addition. Is there anything wrong with my answer? :(

Comment: @user27286 No you didn't, actually. What you described is an XOR operation, not an adder. That's why I put the link to know if he/she knew this.

Comment: @Lena Oh. I thought adding |0> and |1> is just xor of these two and the carry part I didn't use. I will delete the answer...I misinterpreted completely and no point answering it now because you shared the link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a half adder for x number of qubits with min. cost?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16271/how-to-make-a-half-adder-for-x-number-of-qubits-with-min-cost)

Comment: @luciano is an ADD gate the same as a half-adder? Why did you choose to close this qurstion as a duplicate of that?

Comment: This question describes something closer to a "half adder". More importantly, the answer to the previous question answers exactly this question. Maybe the title for the old question needs to be edited to make that more obvious? Shall I copy that answer here?

Answer (score 1):

The method of creating  a quantum adder circuit is similar to how a half or full adder circuit is designed in elementary digital electronics. These circuits add numbers in the binary representation.

For example, for the half adder, there are 2 bits to be added (A and B). These are taken to be the inputs. The output has 2 bits - a sum bit (S)which is the least significant bit of the output and a carry bit (C) which is the MSB. For example, if the inputs to be added are 1 and 1, the result would be carry=1 and sum=0.

To figure out the logic for the adder, write the truth table for the operation:

A  B    C  S

0  0     0  0

0  1     0  1

1  0     0  1

1  1     1  0

For the quantum half adder, take 1 qubit each to represent A,B,C and S respectively. A and B are initialized to the input bits that you wish to add. (For example if you want to add 1 and 0, initialize A = |1> and B=|0>).

Now we need to determine the quantum gates which can take A and B as inputs and give C and S as the outputs - this is like boolean logic minimization. Look at bit C in the truth table - it is 1 only when both A and B are 1. So, C can be obtained by a CCNOT operation using A and B as inputs and C as target. Also, S is a classical XOR operation - this can be achieved by 2 successive CNOTs, both havong S as target and one with A as control and other with B as control.

Keep in mind that the advantage of a quantum adder could be to add several possible input combinations in one go by creating superpostion states in A and B.

You may refer to [this example present in the knowldege base of the Quantum Inspire platform by TU Delft](https://www.quantum-inspire.com/kbase/full-adder/)  for quantum circuits for adders. The qiskit textbook also has an example of how to implement a quantum adder [here](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-states/atoms-computation.html#adder). It explaines how to apply the appropriate quantum gates, and it should be possible to follow this approach to implement the circuit of your choice.