# How to make a half adder for x number of qubits with min. cost?

Tags: programming, qiskit, circuit-construction, ibm-q-experience, quantum-circuit

How to make a half adder for `N` inputs and getting the output on another `x+1` output. Where `x` is numbers of qubit and `N=2^x`. please take a example of a circuit(x must be greater then 4 or 5 for example purpose ) for more understanding . Here is the [example](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-states/atoms-computation.html#4.3-Adding-with-Qiskit-) for 2 qubit half adder.

Answer (score 4):

Qiskit includes [an adder in the circuit library](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.WeightedAdder.html). Here is a quick introduction to it.

Let's say you wan to add two numbers, one of them is three-bit-long, the other one two-bit-long numbers. You will need a 5 qubit adder. That's the first parameter to `qiskit.circuit.library.WeightedAdder`. The second parameter is the *weight* of each of these qubits. Because the fist value is composed by $q_0 \times  2^0 + q_1 \times 2^1 + q_2 \times  2^2$, each of the weights is $2^0$, $2^1$, and $2^2$. The same applies to the second two-bit summand.

```
from qiskit.circuit.library.arithmetic import WeightedAdder
circuit = WeightedAdder(5, [1, 2, 4, 1, 2])
```

This creates a circuit, partially printed here:

```
circuit.draw()
```

```
  state_0: ──■────■────■──────────■────■──────────■────■─────────■────────»
             │    │    │          │    │          │    │         │        »
  state_1: ──┼────┼────┼──────────┼────┼──────────┼────┼─────────┼────────»
             │    │    │          │    │          │    │         │        »
  state_2: ──┼────┼────┼──────────┼────┼──────────┼────┼─────────┼────────»
             │    │    │          │    │          │    │         │        »
  state_3: ──┼────┼────┼──────────┼────┼──────────┼────┼─────────┼────────»
             │    │    │          │    │          │    │         │        »
  state_4: ──┼────┼────┼──────────┼────┼──────────┼────┼─────────┼────────»
             │  ┌─┴─┐  │   ┌───┐  │    │          │    │         │        »
    sum_0: ──■──┤ X ├──┼───┤ X ├──┼────┼──────────┼────┼─────────┼────────»
             │  └───┘  │   └───┘┌─┴─┐  │   ┌───┐  │    │         │        »
    sum_1: ──┼─────────■────────┤ X ├──┼───┤ X ├──┼────┼─────────┼────────»
             │         │        └─┬─┘  │   └───┘┌─┴─┐  │  ┌───┐  │   ┌───┐»
    sum_2: ──┼─────────┼──────────┼────■────────┤ X ├──┼──┤ X ├──■───┤ X ├»
             │         │          │    │        └─┬─┘┌─┴─┐└───┘  │   └───┘»
    sum_3: ──┼─────────┼──────────┼────┼──────────┼──┤ X ├───────┼────────»
           ┌─┴─┐       │          │    │          │  └─┬─┘       │        »
  carry_0: ┤ X ├───────■──────────■────┼──────────┼────┼─────────┼────────»
           └───┘     ┌─┴──┐            │          │    │         │        »
  carry_1: ──────────┤0   ├────────────■──────────■────┼─────────■────────»
                     │    │          ┌─┴──┐            │       ┌─┴──┐     »
  carry_2: ──────────┤  X ├──────────┤0   ├────────────■───────┤0   ├─────»
                     │    │          │  X │                    │  X │     »
control_0: ──────────┤1   ├──────────┤1   ├────────────────────┤1   ├─────»
                     └────┘          └────┘                    └────┘     »
```

Let's now measure the quantum registers `sum` and `carry` to extract the result of the computation:

```
from qiskit import ClassicalRegister

sum_result = ClassicalRegister(4, name='sum_result')
carry_result = ClassicalRegister(3, name='carry_result')
circuit.add_register(sum_result)
circuit.add_register(carry_result)
q_sum = circuit.qregs[1]
q_carry = circuit.qregs[2]

circuit.measure(q_sum, sum_result)
circuit.measure(q_carry, carry_result)
```

And now, let's create value summands. For example, $4$ (three-bit length) and $2$ (two-bit length)

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

value1 = QuantumCircuit(3, name='value1')
value2 = QuantumCircuit(2, name='value2')

# bin(4) == 0b100
value1.x(2)

# bin(2) == 0b10
value2.x(1)
```

The inputs should be appended to the front of the adder circuit, like this:

```
circuit.compose(value1.to_gate(), qubits=[0, 1 ,2], front=True, inplace=True)
circuit.compose(value2.to_gate(), qubits=[3, 4], front=True, inplace=True)

circuit.draw()
```

```
                ┌─────────┐                                                    »
       state_0: ┤0        ├──■────■────■──────────■────■──────────■────■───────»
                │         │  │    │    │          │    │          │    │       »
       state_1: ┤1 value1 ├──┼────┼────┼──────────┼────┼──────────┼────┼───────»
                │         │  │    │    │          │    │          │    │       »
       state_2: ┤2        ├──┼────┼────┼──────────┼────┼──────────┼────┼───────»
                ├─────────┤  │    │    │          │    │          │    │       »
       state_3: ┤0        ├──┼────┼────┼──────────┼────┼──────────┼────┼───────»
                │  value2 │  │    │    │          │    │          │    │       »
       state_4: ┤1        ├──┼────┼────┼──────────┼────┼──────────┼────┼───────»
                └─────────┘  │  ┌─┴─┐  │   ┌───┐  │    │          │    │       »
         sum_0: ─────────────■──┤ X ├──┼───┤ X ├──┼────┼──────────┼────┼───────»
                             │  └───┘  │   └───┘┌─┴─┐  │   ┌───┐  │    │       »
         sum_1: ─────────────┼─────────■────────┤ X ├──┼───┤ X ├──┼────┼───────»
                             │         │        └─┬─┘  │   └───┘┌─┴─┐  │  ┌───┐»
         sum_2: ─────────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────■────────┤ X ├──┼──┤ X ├»
                             │         │          │    │        └─┬─┘┌─┴─┐└───┘»
         sum_3: ─────────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────┼──────────┼──┤ X ├─────»
                           ┌─┴─┐       │          │    │          │  └─┬─┘     »
       carry_0: ───────────┤ X ├───────■──────────■────┼──────────┼────┼───────»
                           └───┘     ┌─┴──┐            │          │    │       »
       carry_1: ─────────────────────┤0   ├────────────■──────────■────┼───────»
                                     │    │          ┌─┴──┐            │       »
       carry_2: ─────────────────────┤  X ├──────────┤0   ├────────────■───────»
                                     │    │          │  X │                    »
     control_0: ─────────────────────┤1   ├──────────┤1   ├────────────────────»
                                     └────┘          └────┘                    »
  sum_result: 4/═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════»
                                                                               »
carry_result: 3/═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════»
                                                                               »
```

Finally, it is time to run the circuit and see how it works:

```
from qiskit import BasicAer, execute
backend = BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')

result = execute(circuit, backend).result()

result.get_counts()
```

```
{'000 0110': 1024}
```

The result is $4+2 = 6$ (`int('0110', base=2)`).